# How can CMake FetchContent be used to import libraries that work with find_package?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I was reading through the [CMake Importing and Exporting Guide](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html) and wanted to adapt one of the examples to make use of [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) instead of `find_package`. But I receive errors related to target not being found and headers not being found.

I have two directories; one called `MathFunctions` and another called `Downstream`. `MathFunctions` exports targets for `Downstream` to use. The directories for each are as follows:

```
MathFunctions          Downstream 
∟ CMakeLists.txt       ∟ CMakeLists.txt
∟ Config.cmake.in      ∟ main.cc
∟ MathFunctions.cxx
∟ MathFunctions.h
```

The following are the `CMakeLists.txt` files in the respective directories.

```
# MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(MathFunctions)

# make cache variables for install destinations
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# create library
add_library(MathFunctions STATIC MathFunctions.cxx)
add_library(MathFunctions::MathFunctions ALIAS MathFunctions)

target_compile_features(MathFunctions PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

# add include directories
target_include_directories(MathFunctions
                           PUBLIC
                           "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
                           "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
)

# install the target and create export-set
install(TARGETS MathFunctions
        EXPORT MathFunctionsTargets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

# install header file
install(FILES MathFunctions.h DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# generate and install export file
install(EXPORT MathFunctionsTargets
        FILE MathFunctionsTargets.cmake
        NAMESPACE MathFunctions::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MathFunctions
)

# include CMakePackageConfigHelpers macro
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# set version
set(version 3.4.1)

set_property(TARGET MathFunctions PROPERTY VERSION ${version})
set_property(TARGET MathFunctions PROPERTY SOVERSION 3)
set_property(TARGET MathFunctions PROPERTY
  INTERFACE_MathFunctions_MAJOR_VERSION 3)
set_property(TARGET MathFunctions APPEND PROPERTY
  COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING MathFunctions_MAJOR_VERSION
)

# generate the version file for the config file
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION "${version}"
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

# create config file
configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfig.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MathFunctions
)

# install config files
install(FILES
          "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfig.cmake"
          "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfigVersion.cmake"
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MathFunctions
)

# generate the export targets for the build tree
export(EXPORT MathFunctionsTargets
       FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/MathFunctionsTargets.cmake"
       NAMESPACE MathFunctions::
)
```

```
# Downstream/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Downstream)

# find MathFunctions
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    MathFunctions
    GIT_REPOSITORY "/path_to_dir/MathFunctions"
    GIT_TAG master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(MathFunctions)

# create executable
add_executable(myexe main.cc)

target_compile_features(myexe PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE MathFunctions::MathFunctions)
```

When I run `cmake -S . -B ./build` in the `Downstream` directory, I receive the following error:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (add_executable):
  Target "myexe" links to target "MathFunctions::MathFunctions" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

What is the right way to do this?

EDIT (28/4/2021):
It seems to work fine when I remove the namespace in the call to `target_link_libraries` to `target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE MathFunctions)` and also add `target_include_directories(myexe PUBLIC ${MathFunctions_SOURCE_DIR})` right after. However, this is still not what I want since I'd like the exported target to be namespace and also avoid the call to `target_include_directories`.

Comment: `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` consumes the **source tree** of the external project. If you want to consume the project's **install tree**, which contains targets exported via `install(EXPORT)`, then you need to install that project and use `find_package` to locate it. If you want to consume the project's **build tree**, which contains targets exported via `export()`, then you need to build the project first and use `find_package` too.

Comment: I'd like to have the same external api as libraries like Catch2 (https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md#top); Catch2 supports both `find_package` and `FetchContent`.

Comment: You may create an ALIAS named `MathFunctions::MathFunctions` for target `MathFunctions`. So you could link with `MathFunctions::MathFunctions` like in case of exported targets.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do create an `ALIAS` in `MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt` in the second call to `add_library`. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Hm, yes, you seems correctly create an ALIAS. Probably, something else wrong in your settings. BTW, `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` is technically an `add_subdirectory`. When debug your project, you could replace FetchContent with `add_subdirectory` call, so it simplifies the project. Have you tried that way?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I tried the same thing that is mentioned in the *Overview* section here:  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html. I receive the same error.

Comment: Have you solved this issues ? Getting the same errors in a very similar setup.